# passing parameters to an event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jquery how can you pass additional parameters to an event handler function?

So for example

```
mySaveFunction: function(i) {
var msg = "my message " + i;
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: this.successFunction, // i want to pass msg to successFunction
  ...
});

successFunction: function(response) {
   // do something with msg

},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An anonymous function should do the trick here. Inside the anonymous function though, `this.successFunction` will be undefined, so we need to store a reference to `this` outside of the anonymous function.

```
var that = this;

$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function() {
        that.successFunction(msg);
    }
    ...
});
```

Comment: `this` will still be something other than `successFunction` probably expects, with the code above. (It will be the global object.) There is no purpose served by your putting it in a variable first, you're not preserving `this` by doing that.

Comment: No, but I'm preserving `successFunction` so that I can call it when `this` has changed. Right?

Comment: Actually, you're both right (of course). Removing the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a closure for that:

```
mySaveFunction: function(i) {
    var self = this; // <=== Grab what `this` is
    var msg = "my message " + i;
    $.ajax({
      ...
      success: function(response) {
          self.successFunction(response, msg); // <=== Use it and `msg `here
      ...
    });
// ...

successFunction: function(response) {
   // do something with msg
},
```

Comment: @Esailija: Fair point, so useful that jQuery provides that in this one case (`ajax`). I'll leave it, but expect that people will see the comment and understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.proxy`:

```
mySaveFunction: function(i) {
    var msg = "my message " + i;
    $.ajax({
          ...
        success: $.proxy(this.successFunction, this, msg), // i want to pass msg to 
          ...
    });
},
successFunction: function(msg, response) {
    // do something with msg
},
```

[Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy) Although the partial application is still undocumented but is [implemented](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7783)

Answer (score -1):

You could use a closure:

```
mySaveFunction: function(i) {
var msg = "my message " + i;
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function(response) {
       alert(msg);  /* msg is available here */
  }
  ...
});
```

Comment: That's not a closure, that's an anonymous function.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: It's both.

Comment: Is it? My understanding of closures must be off, then. I'll take your word for it, though. :)

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: Yes, it closes over the context in which its defined (which includes `msg`). More to explore: *[Closures are not complicated](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)*

Answer (score -1):

Use an anonymous function:

```
  success: function() {
    this.successFunction(parameters);
  }
```

Comment: This won't work because `this` won't be what you wanted it to be so `this.successFunction` won't be right.

Comment: `this` here will be `window`.

Comment: I left out the part where I would do var self=this; before defining the handler and then use self inside the anonymous function.